# Control is not waiting to read for string object

Tags: java

What is the problem with this code? When I execute it control is waiting to read.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int T,N; 
    String configurationl; 
    System.out.println("Enter the number of test cases."); 
    java.util.Scanner sc=new java.util.Scanner(System.in); 
    T=sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter the configuration"); 
    configurationl=sc.nextLine(); 
    System.out.println("The configuration is: "+ configurationl);
}
```

Comment: Do not post links to code. StackOverflow is intended to help _future_ readers as well as the OP, and links that will go bad make the question useless.  Even worse are links to _images_ of code... that cannot be copy/pasted into an IDE.

Comment: Did the below answer help you last year,  Biswaranjan? It is somewhat customary to reply to the people who try to assist here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to put the second input line - to take the `configuration1` into a for loop to run `T` number of times and display it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int T, N;
    System.out.println("Enter number of test cases: ");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    T = in.nextInt();

    String configuration1;

    for (int i = 0; i < T; i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter the configuration: ");
        configuration1 = in.next();
        System.out.println("The configuration is: " + configuration1);
    }
}
```

Then the output will be

```
Enter number of test cases: 
3
Enter the configuration: 
10
The configuration is: 10
Enter the configuration: 
20
The configuration is: 20
Enter the configuration: 
30
The configuration is: 30
```